# Promise behavior with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, deferred

I'm trying to compare two approaches of using promises in angular after reading [this article](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

So I use this code to compare with/without using deferred. Note: the adress http://localhost:1337/error returns a response with an http 500 status and a message "error" as error data (it is the intended behavior).

```
.controller("HomeCtrl", function($q, $http) {
    function doAsyncCallDeferred() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://localhost:1337/error")
            .catch(function(errorData) {
                // error
                deferred.reject(errorData.data);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function doAsyncCall() {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:1337/error")
            .catch(function(errorData) {
                // error
                return errorData.data;
            });
    }

    doAsyncCallDeferred()
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log("with deferred success");
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(errorData) {
            // data should be "error"
            console.log("with deferred error");
            console.log(errorData);
        });

    doAsyncCall()
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log("without deferred success");
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(errorData) {
            // data should be "error"
            console.log("without deferred error");
            console.log(errorData);
        });
})
```

But I am confused by the result :

```
with deferred error
error
without deferred success
error
```

I was assuming that with both approaches, the catch callback would be executed, but it seems that it's not the case. Do anyone can explain this behavior please ?

Comment: I guess it is because this line: `deferred.reject(errorData.data);`. It rejects the deferred, so outside the function still catchable. Could you verify?

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) (in `doAsyncCallDeferred`)! Notice that you're never fulfilling the deferred when the ajax call succeeds.

Comment: @Bergi, he *is* trying to avoid it - the first link is to the article about deferred antipattern

Comment: @NewDev: Oh, right. I should read the questions more carefully.

Comment: @Joy it rejects the rejected promise data, the string "error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` and `.catch` are the async "equivalent" of `try`/`catch`. When you `.catch` something, it means that you "handled" it.

In `doAsyncCall` you are handling the "exception" (which is a promise rejection) and returning `errorData.data` as `data` to the next `.then`. If you want to "re-throw", then `return $q.reject(errorData.data)`.

In `doAsyncCallDeferred` you are explicitly rejecting a promise.

By way of example, the following are equivalent to their users:

```
function doAsyncCallDeferred() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://httpstat.us/500")
        .then(function(response){
           deferred.resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(errorData) {
           deferred.reject(errorData.data);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function doAsyncCall() {
    return $http
             .get("http://httpstat.us/500")
             .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
             })
             .catch(function(errorData){
                return $q.reject(errorData.data);
             });

}
```

Comment: A working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39heccq1/

Comment: @Joy, I would actually demo it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/mvrm0b1w/1/, since it is often desirable to "handle" the error to generate a new service-specific error message. (and, in fact, to make it equivalent to the `doAsyncCallDeferred` result)

Comment: Did you make it wrongly? Seems exactly same as my demo.

Comment: @Joy, yeah - forgot to save - I updated the link. thanks

Comment: Nice, I learned it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I understand ! Thanks for your help/explanations.